# Doodling in java (mouse listener)

Tags: java

I am trying to recreate the doodling thing I made in python (it was an earlier question I asked) in java. However, it keeps giving me an error:

```
Design3.java:28: error: <identifier> expected
   public void paint(x, y, Graphics g) { 
                      ^
Design3.java:28: error: <identifier> expected
   public void paint(x, y, Graphics g) { 
                         ^
2 errors
```

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class Design3 extends Applet implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
   int mx, my;
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      mx = e.getX();
      my = e.getY();
      paint(mx, my, g);
   }
   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
   
   }
   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
   
   }
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
   
   }
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
   
   }
   public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
   
   }
   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
   
   }
   public void paint(x, y, Graphics g) { 
      for (int i = 40; i >= 1; i -= 10) {
         if (i % 3 == 1) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
         } else if (i % 3 == 2) {
            g.setColor(Color.blue); 
         } else {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
         }
         g.fillOval((int)(x + 20 - i / 2), (int)(y + 20 - i / 2), i, i);
      }  
   }
}
```

My question is:
How do I fix the error and make it work?

Comment: Method parameters require types. E.g. `(int x, int y, Graphics g)`

Comment: Also, unless you REALLY REALLY need to use an applet (some old defunct browser app?) you should go with a JFrame / JPanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void paint(int x, int y, Graphics g) {

}
```

You forgot to specify what x and y were.